# How to identify the paymentMethod Token for selected payment option using braintree BTDropInController to create subcriptions?

Tags: node.js, swift, braintree

How to know which card did the user choose from the dropIn UI (which is stores in the vault)?

**Swift code:**

```
let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
{ (controller, result, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        print("ERROR")
    } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
        print("CANCELLED")
    } else if let result = result {
        // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
        // result.paymentOptionType
        // result.paymentMethod
        // result.paymentIcon
        // result.paymentDescription
        let urlString = fullURLString(baseURL: baseURL(), apiPath: CHECKOUT_API_PATH)
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
           "payment_method_nonce" : result.paymentMethod?.nonce ?? ""
        ]

        // ??????????????????? how to get paymentMethod Token?????
    }
}
```

For ***transaction*** we can use result.paymentMethod?.nonce.

**Node.js:**

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: "1.00",
    paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient, // result.paymentMethod?.nonce ?? from iOS
    options: {
      submitForSettlement: true
    }
  }, function (err, result) {
});
```

However for ***subscriptions***, we need to use paymentMethodToken, but how do we know which one did the user select?

**Node.js:**

```
gateway.subscription.create({
    paymentMethodToken: ???,
    planId: "goldPlanID"
}, function (err, result) {
    console.log('subscription result:', result);
    console.log('subscription err:', err);

    res.send(result)
});
```

By using find function in customer, we can get the paymentMethods (but we don't know which one the user selected at client/iOS side:

**Node.js:**

```
gateway.customer.find(customerBraintreeID, function(err, customer) {
...
}
```

**PaymentMethods.token**

```
{
"paymentMethods":
[ CreditCard {
...
token: 'jxxxxx',
uniqueNumberIdentifier: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
updatedAt: 
venmoSdk: false,
verifications: [],
maskedNumber: '411111******1111',
expirationDate: '01/2020' }
...
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. Contact [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com) if you have further questions.</sub>

You can use the payment method nonce returned from the Drop-in UI for creating subscriptions. You do not need to use the payment method token. Rather than passing a `paymentMethodToken`, use [`paymentMethodNonce`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/node#payment_method_nonce). From the Braintree dev docs:

> A payment method must be vaulted before you can associate it with a subscription, so it's usually simplest to refer to the payment method using its paymentMethodToken. However, there are 2 cases where you can pass a payment method nonce instead of a payment method token:
>
> - If the nonce was generated by our Drop-in UI and you passed a customerId when generating the client token, or
> - If the nonce was generated from a vaulted payment method belonging to the customer that will own the subscription

As an example, your request would look like this:

```
gateway.subscription.create({
    paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
    planId: "goldPlanID"
}, function (err, result) {
    console.log('subscription result:', result);
    console.log('subscription err:', err);

    res.send(result)
});
```